# Add string after last text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to build a website using `jquery-1.10.2` where I want to replace css related strings like `<style>`, `<link>` etc. with comment string `<!-- -->`.So far I've managed to replace them by `<!--` but I can't find a way to add `-->` by regex since I'm noob about regex. Here are my codes,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnUpdate').click(function () {
    $('#divText').val($('#divText').val().replace(/<\/?style.*?>|<\/?link.*?>/, "<!--"));
});
```

});

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/89y9nuv1/)

How can I add `-->` after the last string? Need this help badly. Thanks.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a fan of using regex to modify html content, so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnUpdate').click(function() {
    var $tmp = $('<div />', {
      html: $('#divText').val()
    });

    $tmp.find('link, style').replaceWith(function() {
      return document.createComment(this.outerHTML);
    });

    $('#divText').val($tmp.html());
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnUpdate').click(function() {
    var $tmp = $('<div />', {
      html: $('#divText').val()
    });

    $tmp.find('link, style').replaceWith(function() {
      return document.createComment(this.outerHTML);
    });

    $('#divText').val($tmp.html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="divText" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;">
  something

  <link href="//abc.comd/ss.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <style>
    div: {color: red;}
  </style>

  <div>adf</div>
</textarea>
<br>
<button id="btnUpdate">Update</button>
```

Comment: I thought the goal was to actually *remove* the tags, but apparently that's not the case. I didn't know about createComment, so that's nice. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use capturing groups.

```
$('#divText').val($('#divText').val().replace(/(<\/?(?:style|link).*?>)/, "<!-- $1 -->"));
```

OR

```
$('#divText').val($('#divText').val().replace(/(<\/?(?:style|link)[^>]*>)/, "<!-- $1 -->"));
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hV3vW8/1)

Comment: You might want to add an optional ending space or / in case non-HTML 5 is used.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just try to remove those attributes with `removeAttr`?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnUpdate').click(function () {
    $('#divText').val($('#divText').removeAttr("style");
});
```